# How to wrap Closeable to flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to convert synchronous Reader to flow. First attempt looks like this:

```kotlin
flow<Int> {
  val r = new FileReader("...")
  while (true) {
    emit(r.read())  
  } 
}.onCompletion {
   r.close() // oops, r is not accessible here
}
```

Threading is not relevant here so I omitted those detais.

How to allocate resource when flow is subscribed to and how to close it when flow completes?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is simple:

```kotlin
flow<Int> {
  new FileReader("...").use { r -> // will close reader on success, exception, cancellation
    while (true) {
      emit(r.read())  
    }
  } 
}
```